# SQL - Return Employee's Who Haven't Completed Course

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables.

**Users**

```
EmpID | FirstName | Lastname
```

**Quiz_Grades**

```
ID | QuizID | EmpID | Grade
```

**Quiz**

```
QuizID | Course | Name
```

I need to essentially find out which Employee's have NOT done particular quiz's and what the quiz ID is for that quiz.

The Tables are joined pretty much using the below code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Quiz_Grades g ON u.EmpID = g.EmpID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Quiz q ON g.QuizID = q.QuizID
```

This will show me all the users and any Quiz's that they have done obviously, I just instead need to know which users have not done any of the Quiz's listed in the Quiz Table, this is done by using the Quiz_Grades (This is what shows what Quiz's they have done) and finding out which Quiz's Exist in the Quiz Table but they have not been completed by that Employee.

Any assistance please as this is doing my head in.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is a cross join that will show every user with every quiz and then left join with the table that has the info if the user did it or not.

```
select
     a.userud, a.quizid,
     case when qg.quizid is null then 'not done' else 'done' end as status
from (select distinct e.empid, q.quizid from users cross join quiz) a
     LEFT JOIN
     Quiz_Grades qg ON a.empid = qg.empid
                       and a.quizid = qg.quizid
```

Comment: Legend - I need to look into using CROSS JOIN's more often!

Comment: @Lynchie Hi there, glad that you liked it. **If** is the answer of your choice, please consider in accepting it (Clik on the V icon in the left).

Answer (score 1):

You need a cross Join of `Quiz` and `Users`. So you have every Emploee with every Quiz. Now you can join this construct with a `Left join` to the grades that will get you a table where all employee with every quiz has a row but every combination where the user does not have the grade yet there will be a `null` so youre where statement must be something like `where Grade is not null`.

```
Select  *
from    Users u
cross join quiz q
left outer join quiz_grades qg
on      u.EmpId = qg.EmpId and
        q.QuizID = qg.QuizID
where   qg.Grade is not null
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When writing code, please format it properly by selecting it and clicking on the braces on the top bar of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE NOT (SELECT * FROM Quiz_Grades WHERE u.EmpID = g.EmpID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Quiz q ON g.QuizID = q.QuizID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u
CROSS JOIN Quiz q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                  FROM Quiz_Grades g 
                  WHERE u.EmpID = g.EmpID 
                  AND g.QuizID = q.QuizID)
```

Essentially get all Quiz's where there is not grade per user